# Open files containing string intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When looking for strings in a project (`Ctrl + Shift + F`) occurrences are shown; how can you open all files with said strings? In this case a string may appear in several files making it difficult to track.

There are many files that contain found string; how can they all be opened in intellij?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing Ctrl + Shift + F then press Shift + Enter, (or press the Open in Find Window), to have all occurrences listed in a dedicated window. E.g. see: [image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Press `Ctrl + Shift + F` or Windows or `Cmd + Shift + F` on Mac to search for a string.
2. From the result list select which you would want to open by holding `Ctrl` (Windows) or `Cmd` (MacOS) and clicking on the entries:
   [image]

3. Press `Enter` to open all the selections.

If you would want to open every file from the search results, select the first entry, hold `Shift` and select the last entry, and press `Enter`.

Comment: Thank you this is the correct answer, so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Edit > Find > Find in Path

**Ctrl + Shift + F**

Documentation: Find the search string in a project.

Comment: How can all files in which the string was found be automatically opened in the editor?

Comment: ok sorry you cant automatically open everything